# Three.JS: Drawing texture directly to canvas without creating a plane (in a billboard fashion)

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I'm rendering a custom texture using a `WebGLRenderTarget`. What I need now is to be able to draw the resulting `renderTarget.texture` directly to the canvas, without adding it to a plane first.

The reason for this is that my camera is orbiting and moving a lot, and I want the texture to be fixed on the top-right corner, like a billboard, without getting left behind.[image: Example]

My pseudo-code looks like this:

```
// Create renderer 1
var renderer1 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer1.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer1.domElement);

// Create renderer 2
var renderer2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer2.setSize(100, 100);
document.body.appendChild(renderer2.domElement);

var renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(100, 100);

// Create texture to renderTarget
renderer1.render(textureScene, ortoCam, renderTarget, false);

// Render textureScene to second renderer to see texture
renderer2.render(textureScene, ortoCam);

// Render the rest of the scene, with a moving perspective camera
renderer1.render(scene, perspCam);
```

This works, but feels very inefficient, especially since I'm creating a second renderer to add a second 100x100 canvas. Is there any way to grab the `renderTarget.texture` and draw it on top of the first canvas so I can skip using the second renderer? I need the renderTarget output to create height maps, but also need it to be visible in a billboard fashion on the top-right corner.

**Update:**
I've tried creating a 2D canvas context and using `context.drawImage(this.renderTarget.texture.image, 10, 10, 20, 20);` but `renderTarget.texture.image` is undefined. Any ideas why I can't get that image data?

Comment: you dont need a second renderer, you dont even need a second scene but it would make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only need a single renderer.

You can render an overlay inset by using a pattern like so:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.autoClear = false; // important!
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

In the `render()` function,

```
renderer.clear();

// render to texture
renderer.render( texture_scene, ortho_camera, renderTarget, true );

// render scene first
renderer.setViewport( 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.render( scene, camera );

// render inset second
renderer.clearDepth(); // clear the depth buffer
renderer.setViewport( 10, window.innerHeight - insetHeight - 10, insetWidth, insetHeight );
renderer.render( inset_scene, ortho_camera );
```

three.js r.84

Comment: Hmm... I didn't know about the `setViewport()` method. What is `inset_scene`? Is that the same as the `texture_scene`?

Comment: The `inset_scene` in your case would likely be a "full-screen-quad" -- just a plane in front of the orthographic camera with `plane.material.map = renderTarget.texture;`

Comment: Ah, I see. So there's no native way to "paint" the texture being output by `WebGLRenderTarget` directly to the canvas? I was hoping to avoid a third scene and render call, but this should work!

Comment: there is no way to draw anything onto a screen without using a draw call. In order to have anything rasterized, you need to have some geometry. Other than a clear call.

Answer (score 0):

I made an npm module that should render a screen quad using mostly the shaders and a high level interface ( width , height , top , left ).

Right now the fragment shader is not reading a texture but in the readme there is a simple fragment shader that you can use for that.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-screen-quad